# mypy does not infer generic type T with Optional[Any]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

I have a problem with mypy and generic T parameter. I am using sqlalchemy sessions **get()** method to retrieve something from the database (the code works). I am injecting (self.model=model) one of my SqlalchemyORM models that I have defined somewhere else.

Mypy is giving me this message:

```
Variable "my_project.repositories.sql_repo.Foo.Optional" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]mypy
See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliasesmypy
```

```
T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[T], db: db_session) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.db = db
    def get_by_id(self, item_id: int) -> Optional[T]:
     
        return self.session().get(self.model,item_id)
```

Comment: What does `Optional` refer to in this case? Is it `typing.Optional` or something else?

Comment: `typing.Optional`. The reason I put it there is because before I had `-> T`, in that case I got this : `Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[T]", expected "T")  [return-value]` so It just made sense to convert it to `-> Optional[T]`  @Julia

Answer (score 0):

Error was in my import, I accidentally imported "from typing import Optional" inside my class. Of course the import should be at the top level. Mind you I still do not completely understand the meaning of mypy error.

```
# ..... IMPORT SHOULD BE AT THE TOP  ...
from typing import Optional
# .............................

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):

    # ..... HERE WAS THE ERROR  ...
    from typing import Optional
    # .............................


    def __init__(self, model: Type[T], db: db_session) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.db = db
    def get_by_id(self, item_id: int) -> Optional[T]:
     
        return self.session().get(self.model,item_id)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).